# Get user's event list

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-fql

I just started to use FQL, and I was trying some FB examples that worked fine.

But I try to make my own exapmles, but didn't work...

I was trying to get the list of activities of a loged user, with this FQL code:

```
$f = new Facebook($configure); //configure is already ok
$user_id = $f->getUser();

if($user_id){
    $ret = $f->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 
                         'query' => 'select eid, uid, rsvp_status 
                                     from event_member 
                                     where uid = '.$user_id.';'));

    //I splitted the query here because is too long.
    //In my PHP code is all in one line

    print_r($ret);
}
```

but it returns a empty array.

I try it with my FB profile, even I accepted some incoming events, but I still get an empty list...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [query event\_member table by uid](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8361715/query-event-member-table-by-uid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the query is perfectly right. I got the result using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20eid%2C%20uid%2C%20rsvp_status%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from%20event_member%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20where%20uid%20%3D%20%27UID%27%3B).

Have you set the permissions: `user_events` and `friends_events` for the user?

Comment: I had the user_events, but the friend_events was not setted. But, I tried to get the users of an activity (... where eid = XXX) and it worked...

Comment: Well, in the FB debug page it works... so, I think you are right and I need to set the permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fix the problem...

The problem was in the redirect. I changed it to:

```
header("Location: ".$f->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_events, friends_events', 'redirect_uri' => 'mywebsite')
```